# depthimage_to_laserscan: Cannot call rectifyPoint when distortion is unknown

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the depthimage_to_laserscan with an MYNT EYE camera. I get this output (see the error in the end):

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: base_link
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 3
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3

NODES
  /
depthimage_to_laserscan (depthimage_to_laserscan/depthimage_to_laserscan)
gmapping_node (gmapping/slam_gmapping)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[depthimage_to_laserscan-1]: started with pid [17275]
process[gmapping_node-2]: started with pid [17276]
[ERROR] [1584483469.757240526]: Could not convert depth image to laserscan: Cannot call rectifyPoint when distortion is unknown.
```

My platform: Ubuntu 18.04 (x64). I use ROS Melodic. The "depthimage_to_laserscan" package version is 1.0.8.

The depthimage_to_laserscan node is subscribed to 2 topics (I checked it with rqt_graph):

1. /mynteye/depth/image_raw
2. /mynteye/depth/camera_info

I used "rostopic echo" command to check the messages published to the "/mynteye/depth/camera_info" topic. This message is published continuously:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 22519
  stamp: 
    secs: 1584483432
    nsecs: 228966713
  frame_id: "mynteye_depth_frame"
height: 480
width: 752
distortion_model: "KANNALA_BRANDT"
D: [-0.031170006043024615, 0.02301973375803421, -0.0352997004132725, 0.016822330752111488, 0.0]
K: [366.9709661238975, 0.0, 370.60059198845664, 0.0, 366.9835673211366, 235.15553431559664, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [0.9999976403807529, 0.0012593887617488196, -0.0017700770811053344, -0.0012566534577968802, 0.9999980160222749, 0.0015455657866886375, 0.0017720200374941424, -0.0015433377662572895, 0.9999972390229515]
P: [367.166403809061, 0.0, 338.11387634277344, 0.0, 0.0, 367.166403809061, 188.29586029052734, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
---
```

It looks like the distortion matrix is not empty. What can go wrong there? Maybe the problem is in the unsupported distortion model "KANNALA_BRANDT"?

Thanks,
Eugene

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346935/depthimage_to_laserscan:-cannot-call-rectifypoint-when-distortion-is-unknown/) by [Eugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/52610/eugene/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Maybe the problem is in the unsupported distortion model "KANNALA_BRANDT"?

That is a likely cause, yes.

As [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) mentions, legal values for that field are defined in `sensor_msgs/distortion_models.h`. Looking at that file shows (from [here](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/4804aa31c4df20c2143c7a09627a09039dafc1e0/sensor_msgs/include/sensor_msgs/distortion_models.h#L45-L47)):

> ```
> const std::string PLUMB_BOB = "plumb_bob";
> ```

```
const std::string RATIONAL_POLYNOMIAL = "rational_polynomial";
const std::string EQUIDISTANT = "equidistant";
```

`KANNALA_BRANDT` is not in that list.

It looks like it's also called a *fisheye* distortion model, and for that model there are several PRs open. The one against `ros/common_msgs` would be [ros/common_msgs#151](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/pull/151).

You may be able to get an idea of the current state of support for this particular distortion model from the linked issues and PRs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2